# How can I attach a manual workflow run to a pull request's status checks?

Tags: github-actions, pull-request

I have a workflow which runs a `test` job under given circumstances automatically, or I can run it manually:

```yaml
name: Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      used-branch:
        description: Branch the test shall be run on
        default: master
        required: true
  push:
    branches: ['main', 'master']
    tags: ['!**']
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, ready_for_review]

jobs:
  test:
    steps:
      - name: Checkout selected branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        if: inputs.used-branch != ''
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.used-branch }}
      - name: Checkout current branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{github.ref}}
        if: inputs.used-branch == ''
      - name: Run test
        ...
```

I want the test be required before merging. So I check `Require status check to pass before merging`, `Require branches to be up to date before merging` and specify `test` as required job in the repo's branch settings.

The problem is: when I run the workflow manually (and therefore inject the branch via a variable), it's not related to the branch and its success won't be "discovered" by the PR checks.

Is there another way to link the run to a branch, or another way to propagate the result to the branch's pull request?

Comment: I 100% understand your question and once you start to work around GitHub's API design things get complicated. My best guess is you will need to resort to using the API when running manually... see: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24616 & https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks?apiVersion=2022-11-28 & https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks

Comment: @aknosis Thanks for your response! So there's no "configurable" way to achieve this right now. Well, if that's the answer, then feel free to provide it and I will accept it! I don't see myself tinkering with API for now, I think. A workaround is closing and reopening the PR, and maybe I find a even less wonky way (`pr_comment` don't exist either, sadly) for the time being. :)

Comment: `pr_comment` events are handled via `issue_comment` because pull requests are just issues with code... https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_comment-use-issue_comment

Comment: @aknosis Oh, I see. After skimming briefly over this topic I thought it would mean a comment in a _referred_ issue (for my defense, I hadn't the time for a proper read yet). So thanks for your clarification, maybe that's a good compromise to head for!

Comment: I've spent the last six months buried in GHA so I have got all the bruises from learning it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a minute to digest what you were asking, but now I get it. (Updated title to be more precise).

Short answer, it isn't possible out of the box. Once you start to work around GitHub's API design things get complicated.

The only plausible solution I can think of today is via GitHub API.

See:

- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24616
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks?apiVersion=2022-11-28
- https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks

Comment: > The only plausible solution I can think of today is via GitHub API.

could you expand on this?

Comment: @develobster I haven't explored the checks api before, but essentially you need to map all non `pull_request` triggers to a PR and then use the api to set the proper status on the PR.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do this via the api. You can run a step conditionally based on your manual input, and use the `github.checks.create` action from `github-script`.

Assuming that you give your step `name: Run test` and id of `tests-step`, here is an example:

```
- name: Report tests check
  if: ${{ github.event.inputs.used-branch && steps.tests-step.outcome }}
  uses: actions/github-script@v3
  with:
    github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    script: |
      github.checks.create({
        name: 'run tests',
        head_sha: '${{ github.event.issue.pull_request.head.sha }}',
        status: 'completed',
        conclusion: '${{ steps.tests-step.outcome }}',
        output: {
          title: 'Run tests',
          summary: 'Results: ${{ steps.tests-step.outcome }}'
        },
        owner: context.repo.owner,
        repo: context.repo.repo
      })
```

Note that `GITHUB_TOKEN` is automatically [built in to your workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication).

The `head_sha` parameter is tricky and needs to be there for the commit annotation to work. The `issue` property of `github.event.issue` in this case refers to the PR (github sees it as an "issue") that will be annotated.

The trouble here is that if you run your workflow using `workflow_dispatch`, you will not have access to this value, since there is no PR in the context of a manual run.

One solution would be to have an input requiring the PR number, and a script to get the sha. Here is how you can do that:

```
- name: get sha from PR number and save output
  id: get-sha
  uses: actions/github-script@v3
  with:
    github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    script: |
      console.log('PR number: ' + ${{ github.event.issue.number }})
      const pr = await github.pulls.get({
        owner: context.repo.owner,
        repo: context.repo.repo,
        pull_number: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
      })
      console.log('PR Head sha: ' + pr.data.head.sha)
      core.setOutput('sha', pr.data.head.sha)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, as GitHub doesn't support this as you observed, but a workaround is to trigger the workflow from something that happens with the pull request. E.g. it can be triggered when a label is added to the PR (like "run-tests") or the PR is approved (which [needs a combination of a trigger and job condition](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25372)). A special comment would work as well, though that's less intuitive.

While these are not exactly the dispatch trigger you asked about, but I think they cover the "run workflow manually" use-case.

Comment: Hey, not sure all of this would work, though. I tried an approach where a `\test` comment in the PR triggered the tests, but this didn't update the checks either. For now, I'm switching a PR to `Draft` and back, which triggere a workflow that get actually recognized, similar to what you've suggested.

Comment: @NotX these should work. How does your jobs look like? anyway, I know you said it triggered the tests, but tests that are triggered by `issue_comment` event will only be triggered if the workflow file is in the main branch ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#issue_comment))

Comment: Yep, we actually use the label approach; first tried the PR approval one what also works but we didn't like it for other reasons.

Comment: @develobster You're right, I did some adjustments and it's working. So now a `/test`  comment in the PR triggers a workflow whose result is detected by the PR's status checks.